# Using Left or substring with wildcard in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql

I am looking to retrieve information from a field, but am having troubles getting exactly what I want.  The information I want has no set order and I am also looking for two different things.  Here is an example of the information I am working with.

```
|PEvent|   PDate     |         PDescription                          |
|  3  | 2014-11-21 | Padding, 90 Series, Stage, SF550                |
|  4  | 2014-11-21 | Padding, 45 Series, 144 Stage SF90, 15 spor, AR |
|  5  | 2013-03-06 | 400 Series, 96 STAGE RE FLEX 30                 | 
|  6  | 2015-01-09 | Padding, 20 Series, 13 Stage SF 550, Housing    |
```

What I want to get is SF and the number and FLEX and the number that follows it, in these cases SF550, SF90, SF 550 FLEX 30.  I would also like to get FLEX and the number that follows it.  The problem I am having is that there are so many differences in the data.  I cannot say 10 spaces from the left since it is not always 10 spaces.  I have the same problem from the right.  The other issue I have is that sometimes SF and FLEX will be right against the number where other times there will be a space in between them.

I have created a SQL Fiddle sample database with more records for testing.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e350f)

Comment: Is this a one-off or a business rule thing? Because if you have a business rule that says some important data is going to be input inconsistently into a certain field, I would suggest changing that business rule to save your sanity. If this is just a matter of getting that data for a finite set of records, you might be better off dumping everything to text and then making creative use of regular expressions.

Comment: I am in the process of trying to get this business rule changed, but in the meantime I have been tasked with getting this data in on a nightly basis.  I am hoping that we can shore up how the data is input into the other system in the first place sooner rather than later.

Comment: Not only your SQL Fiddle example contains more rows, it also contains more different cases. For instance, there is this string: `Padding, FLEX 10 400 Series, 11 Stage, BYHMP`. What do you want the result for it to be, `FLEX 10 400 Series` or `FLEX 10`? I'm trying to understand whether there is always a comma after the number or not.

Comment: I am looking for Flex 10 and to eliminate the 400 on these.  Sometimes there is a comma sometimes there is not.  This is an incredible mess with no one ever having set rules on how the data is entered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following assumptions have been made (some of them possibly repeating parts of your description):

1. `SF`/`FLEX` is always followed either by a number immediately or by a space character and then a number.
2. There is always one space character before `SF`/`FLEX`, unless the item is at the beginning of the string.
3. There is always a comma or a space after the number that follows `SF`/`FLEX`, unless the item is at the end of the string.

With those in mind, here is [my approach](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e350f/35):

```
SELECT
  t.*,
  Item = LEFT(item.S, CHARINDEX(' ', item.S + ' ', LEN(prefix.S) + spaces.N + 1))
FROM
  dbo.testdesc AS t
  CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('SF'), ('FLEX')) AS prefix (S)
  CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (1)) AS spaces (N)
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT NULLIF(PATINDEX('% ' + prefix.S + SPACE(spaces.N) + '[0-9]%', ' ' + t.PDescription), 0)) AS startpos (N)
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(',', t.PDescription + ',', startpos.N + LEN(prefix.S) + spaces.N)) AS endpos (N)
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUBSTRING(t.PDescription, startpos.N, endpos.N - startpos.N)) AS item (S)
WHERE
  startpos.N IS NOT NULL
;
```

This is the output of the above query:

```
PEvent  PDate                    PDescription                                               Item
------  -----------------------  ---------------------------------------------------------  -------
3       2014-11-21 00:00:00.000  Padding, 90 Series, Stage, SF550                           SF550
4       2014-11-21 00:00:00.000  Padding, 45 Series, 144 Stage SF90, 15 spor, AR            SF90
8       2013-06-14 00:00:00.000  Padding, 900 Series, 140 Stage SF1100, 1/16, Money, TS XB  SF1100
10      2014-12-30 00:00:00.000  Padding, 444 Series, 47 Stage SF330, 5/9, house            SF330
6       2015-01-09 00:00:00.000  Padding, 20 Series, 13 Stage SF 550, Housing               SF 550
5       2013-03-06 00:00:00.000  400 Series, 96 STAGE RE FLEX 30                            FLEX 30
7       2013-06-14 00:00:00.000  Padding, FLEX 10 400 Series, 11 Stage, BYHMP               FLEX 10
9       2015-02-27 00:00:00.000  Flex 10 40 87 stage                                        Flex 10
```

And to explain some of the trickery employed by the query, this is how it works:

1. The original row set is cross joined with two inline views, one that represents the required prefixes (`prefix`) and one that specifies how many spaces there may be between the prefix and the subsequent number (`spaces`). This way the query will probe for all combinations of prefixes and numbers of delimiting spaces (`SF`, `SF` , `FLEX`, `FLEX` ).
2. The `PDescription` string is searched for each combination, one after one, to calculate the starting position of the prefix. It uses [PATINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx), which, for each prefix and space number, builds its own search pattern. As per the assumptions above, PATINDEX expects a space before the prefix and at least one digit after the prefix and, possibly, a space.

   So, if, for instance, the current prefix is `SF` and the current expected number of spaces after it is 1, the pattern would be `% SF [0-9]%`. To make sure there is a space before the prefix, a space is added at the beginning of `PDescription`.

   That trick accomplishes two things: it helps to find the prefix if it is at the beginning of the string and it makes the resulting starting position accurate. The latter is important because technically the returned position would match not the prefix itself but the preceding space. So, to get the actual position of the prefix, we would need to increment the result by 1. However, because we had added a space at the beginning of the source, all the positions were shifted forward already. So, in the end, the result points exactly at the beginning of the prefix.

   One final touch here is that if the returned position is 0, it is transformed into NULL by [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx). That helps to avoid errors about negative length values passed to SUBSTRING later.
3. The found position is then used in [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to find the first comma in `PDescription` found after that position. Again, to make sure there *is* a comma, the character is appended to `PDescription`. The result constitutes the ending position of the sought item.
4. Using the obtained starting and ending positions, the item is extracted from `PDescription` using the [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) function.
5. Finally, in the SELECT clause, before actually returning the item, the query additionally checks if there is a space after the number, just in case the item was not properly delimited by a comma. By appending a space to the item, it uses the same trick as when searching for the comma position, also taking into account the length of the prefix and the expected number of spaces after the prefix to make sure the found space character will be the one *after* the number.
6. In cases where the prefix is not found in the string, `Item` returns NULL. Such rows, however, are excluded from the output by the WHERE clause, which specifies that the starting position be not NULL.

I am not sure if the above description is clear enough but hopefully it will help together with the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with NReiligh but if you still want to extract values use combination of CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING functions of SQL SERVER

```
SELECT [PEvent]
      ,[PDate]
      , [PDescription]
      ,CASE 
      ------------------------------------------For SF Values 
      WHEN [PDescription] LIKE '%SF%' 
            THEN CASE substring([PDescription], CHARINDEX('SF',[PDescription]), CHARINDEX(' ',[PDescription]+' ', CHARINDEX('SF',[PDescription])) - CHARINDEX('SF',[PDescription]) )
                 WHEN 'SF' 
                 THEN substring([PDescription], CHARINDEX('SF',Replace([PDescription],'SF ','SF'))
                                , CHARINDEX(' ',Replace([PDescription],'SF ','SF')+' ', CHARINDEX('SF',Replace([PDescription],'SF ','SF'))) 
                                - CHARINDEX('SF',Replace([PDescription],'SF ','SF'))+1 
                               )
                 ELSE substring([PDescription], CHARINDEX('SF',[PDescription]), CHARINDEX(' ',[PDescription]+' ', CHARINDEX('SF',[PDescription])) - CHARINDEX('SF',[PDescription]) ) END 
      ----------------------------------------For FLEX Values
      WHEN [PDescription] LIKE '%FLEX%' 
            THEN CASE substring([PDescription], CHARINDEX('FLEX',[PDescription]), CHARINDEX(' ',[PDescription]+' ', CHARINDEX('FLEX',[PDescription])) - CHARINDEX('FLEX',[PDescription]) )
                 WHEN 'FLEX' 
                 THEN substring([PDescription], CHARINDEX('FLEX',Replace([PDescription],'FLEX ','FLEX'))
                                , CHARINDEX(' ',Replace([PDescription],'FLEX ','FLEX')+' ', CHARINDEX('FLEX',Replace([PDescription],'FLEX ','FLEX'))) 
                                - CHARINDEX('FLEX',Replace([PDescription],'FLEX ','FLEX'))+1 
                               )
                 ELSE substring([PDescription], CHARINDEX('FLEX',[PDescription]), CHARINDEX(' ',[PDescription]+' ', CHARINDEX('FLEX',[PDescription])) - CHARINDEX('FLEX',[PDescription]) ) END 
       ELSE '' END 
  FROM [Database].[dbo].[TableName]
```

Note: My assumption is there is only one space Between SF\FLEX and numbers

Comment: Thank you AA., from looking over the data there are two ways that I have noticed SF\FLEX input.  One with no space at all or having just one space in-between SF\FLEX and the number.